# graphviz issue when spawning Python script from C

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz, webots

I am using a ***graphviz*** library for Python.

When I run the script from terminal, the graph is created, but when I start the script from ***C*** program using ***posix_spawn***, I get error message saying that

> "ValueError: Program dot not found in path" (I have tried all options: 'neato', 'dot', 'twopi', 'circo', 'fdp', 'nop').

My Python script uses ***#!/usr/local/bin/python*** location. I have tried to explicitly use this path and tried out the same sequence:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G = pgv.AGraph(directed=True)
G.add_node(1)
G.get_node(1).attr['label'] = 'hi'
G.draw('test.png', prog='dot')
```

and it worked

I am lost why after calling script using posix_spawn, the graphviz library cannot find the path anymore.

EDIT:

After adding dot path to: bash_profile, bash_rc, and etc/paths, I get /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin when I try printing my path both from Python script and C program, while my echot $PATH has many lines.

Have also tried appending PATH from Python `sys.path.append('/opt/local/bin/dot')`

P.S. I am using Webots as my IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that graphviz isn't in your path. Make sure `$PATH` contains the folder which contains `dot` and the rest of the graphviz tools.

**[EDIT]** I'm not sure where Webots gets its path from; my guess would be that Mac OS/X strips the PATH of processes which you start from the Desktop (or maybe the desktop process is started with a very basic PATH).

For such situations, I usually wrap the C program in an executable script that sets the environment (like the PATH) and then invokes the C program itself. When you execute the script from anywhere, the code will behave as expected.

Comment: may I ask where the 'dot' is usually found?

Comment: If you installed the official package, it's in `/usr/bin`. If you installed it yourself, it might be in `/usr/local/bin`. Try `which dot` and `find / -name dot -type f`; note the latter might take a long time. Some systems have an index of all files. Try `locate dot` but that might not work.

Comment: I found it and added to the PATH, but still the same error

Comment: Then it's still not in the path since the error is "Program `dot` not found in path".

Comment: echo $PATH has the directory where dot resides

Comment: I do not quite like this part: `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz-1.3rc2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1289, in _get_prog` the package name looks strange to me

Comment: `$PATH` must have the folder when the script is running. I'm not very knowledgeable with Mac; but setting the path in one terminal will not pass it to other terminals or to processes which already run. So if you changed the PATH, you may have to relog to make it visible. Also note that changes to your PATH doesn't change it for `root` or other users.

Comment: the PATH contains 'dot' path when new Terminal window is being open since I added it to the .bash_profile

Comment: Add `print(sys.getenv('PATH'))` to your Python script to see the path at runtime.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getenv'`

Comment: Trying `os.environ.get('PATH')` and I get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, which means dot is not there..

Comment: Do the same in your C code; Python inherits the path from it. C code should be `printf("%s\n", getenv("PATH"));`. Then you need to check how the C code is started and why it doesn't get the correct path.

Comment: It is not there either.. as a matter of fact, what I get is just `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, while my PATH in Terminal is 6 lines long... I wonder if that has anything to do with Webots IDE that I am using

Comment: I have tried adding the path to bash_profile, bash_rc, and etc/paths

Comment: How do you start your C program? Does it work when you start it manually from the command line?

Comment: I start the program from Webots IDE, but now I have tried to execute from command line by running `path_to_webots/webots --mode=fast --stdout --stderr world.wbt` and all libraries were found, only the output was saved in different folder (where world.wbt resides). Thank you. Maybe you could explain why this happens?

Comment: See my edits. To find out where the webots path comes from, you'll have to ask a Mac expert :-)